# Ruby Devkit installation not accepting path

Tags: ruby, installation, devkit

I'm trying to install Ruby and Ruby Gems to a new Windows computer (originally on a Mac) and I'm unable to continue.

I have followed, word for word, https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit. Downloaded, extracted to a directory under my Ruby installed path, ran the init command, ran the install command. However I get this message

> Invalid configuration or no Rubies listed. Please fix 'config.yml' and
>   rerun 'ruby dk.rb install'

Ok so I go to config.yml. I add my Ruby installed directory (C:\Program Files (x86)\Ruby) and try the install command again. Same avail. I have tried every possible combination or interpretation of. I even made a sub folder in my Ruby\ directory specifically for gems and didn't work.

Also: Why in the world does it say, in various other places, to "update PATH" when it gives no other instructions as to what that is, where it is, or how to update it

Answer (score 0):

about half way down that page says:

NOTE: The path to your  must not contain any whitespaces (like in “C:\Program Files\Ruby193”). This is very important because whitespaces in the path to your ruby installation will cause certain error messages as soon as you try to install gems which require the DevKit.

change `C:\Program Files (x86)\Ruby` => `C:\Progra~2\Ruby`

Also the PATH is a system environment variable, it's where the system looks for executable, in cmd prompt you can type `echo %PATH%` to see whats in it.
To update it go to Control Panel-> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables and add `C:\Progra~2\Ruby\;` to the System Variable named PATH.